# Bypass Form Validation

Tags: scala, playframework-2.0

I have a form with a radio button group for which I have set the validation logic that one of the radio buttons in the group must be selected on submission.

However I also have a cancel button on that form which I have wrapped as a hyperlink as follows:

```
<a href="@routes.MyController.index">
    <button>Cancel</button>
</a>
```

The issue is that when the user clicks this cancel button when no radio buttons have been selected (because they want to leave the form for some reason) , the validation logic kicks in prompting the user to select a radio button option.

How do I bypass the validation when the cancel button is clicked?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change `button` to `div`:

```
<a href="@routes.MyController.index">
  <div>Cancel</div>
</a>
```

The default `type` attribute is `submit` so it sends the form to the server and validates it. In your case the `button` with the default `submit` attribute catch the click event, so `a` even not hits.

If you need the `button` tag then you need to override its behavior with the javascript like:

```
<button type="button" onclick="window.location.href='@routes.MyController.index'">Cancel</button>
```

P.S.

It's have nothing to do with playframework, it's just an HTML behavior.